How many homomorphism are from Z to the ring of matrices?
Let be $(\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$ and $(\mathcal{M}_{2x2}(\mathbb{Z}) , + ,\cdot)$ rings, and $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathcal{M}_{2x2}(\mathbb{Z})$ a function.
How many ring homomorphisms $\phi$ are?
I was thinking that $\phi \equiv 0 : x \mapsto 0 $ is the only, because in $\mathbb{Z}$ we don't have nilpotent elements and in $\mathcal{M}_{2x2}(\mathbb{Z})$ exist nilpotent elements (and cero divisors)

To any ring $R$ there is a unique homomorphism $Z\to R$ given by $1\mapsto 1_R$ assuming homomorphisms must be unital. This is a nice exercise to try.

By "ring homomorphisms", do you mean group-homomorphisms that are multiplicative, or do you mean group-homomorphisn that are multiplicative and send $1$ to $1$?

Do you mean ring or rng? Rng homomorphism does not require sending 1 to 1.

The question is not asking you for ring isomorphisms, but just homomorphisms. So your $\phi$ does not need to be onto.
If you are requiring $\phi$ to be unital, this limits possibilities a bit. What happens is that you will always have $\phi(n)=n\phi(1)=n\,I_2$. So there is a single homomorphism.
If you don't require $\phi$ to be unital, you still have $\phi(n)=n\,\phi(1)$. But since $\phi$ is multiplicative we need to have $\phi(1)=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)^2$. This is the only restriction, though. Given any $T\in M_2(\mathbb Z)$ with $T^2=T$, the map $\phi(n)=nT$ is additive and multiplicative.
There are infinitely many matrices $T$ as above. There are the obvious ones $0_2$ ,$I_2$, and
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Given any such $T$, a conjugate $STS^{-1}$ is also idempotent for any invertible $S$. So there are infinitely many possible $T$. An easy way to enumerate infinitely many (but not all) possible $T$ is to consider
$$
T_k=\begin{bmatrix} 1&k\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad k\in\mathbb Z.
$$
